# Create Lotus Notes entry from Access Event

Tags: ms-access, vba, lotus-notes

Is it possible to create an entry in a Lotus Notes Calendar, specifically a "reminder" using an Access VBA script when a new entry is made in the Access database table?  I have had a search on google but the only thing I can find so far is send an email to Lotus Notes.  The email option but work if I can create it as a Lotus Notes invitation.  Is that a possible alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you found examples for sending an email, then you found examples on how to open the users mailfile (called dbMail in the following examples) using `OpenMail` method of `NotesDatabase`- class.

Now you just need to create a document using `Set doc = dbMail.CreateDocument` in that database, tell it to be an Appointment by applying the form- item `Call doc.ReplaceItemValue( "Form", "Appointment" )` and then set all the required items. The needed items can be found in [the calendaring and scheduling schema](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/cs_schema_toc) at IBM.

Sorry for not posting specific code, but did not want to put more effort in my answer then you did in your question...

The description of all classes (for LotusScript, but they are mainly the same in VB / VBA) can be found in the Domino Designer- Help you find at various places in the web.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  This gave me some clues.  I also found the following URL's http://www.fabalou.com/vbandvba/lotusnotesappointment.asp and http://www.fabalou.com/VBandVBA/lotusnotesappointment_ver6.asp

Answer (score 0):

If person A can create an appointment for person B, and that appointment is to be created immediately in B's calendar, A would need write-access to B's calendar. If it should work like that for any A and B in the organisation, you'll have a serious problem. That's why Notes works using invitations.

Please define first which of the two applications is leading in your organisation, Notes or the Access Calendar? If it is Notes, you should indeed send invitations, and your application should be inquiring Notes/Domino regularly about the status of the appointments. If it is your Access application, you can indeed put the appointment document directly in the user's database, but that would require write access to all user mail/calendar databases.

We solved a similar problem by creating an intermediary database (application) on the Domino server that is the interface between the (Access) application and the Notes environment. The Notes application runs as a special user, with write-access to all user databases. The Access application can communicate with that database in any way you seem fit: mail, web-services, COM-interface.

Better refrain from writing user mail databases directly. Either send invitations, or create a Notes-based "replicator" application.

Comment: @DBugger Thanks for response.  Notes is the primary email application in this organisation.  The access database is one of our end users own they have created for their role